# Discord.py make the bot wait for a specific answer

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I wanted to code a bot for learning vocabs so when I use -vokabel the bot should send a random vocab. Then the bot should wait for an asnwer and if the answer is the right translation of the word then the bot should send right
here is my code

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    vocab_list = ["suburb",
                  "timer"]

    if message.content.startswith("-vokabeln"):
        random_vokabel = random.choice(vocab_list)
        await message.channel.send(random_vokabel)
        if random_vokabel == "suburb":
            
            if message.content.startswith("Vorort"):
                await message.channel.send('richtig')
```

But this wont work
So when the bot sends Suburb and I send Vorort nothing happens
Can anyone help me how to do this so it works like I want

Answer (score 0):

Try using wait_for [read docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)!

Comment: I know this isn't a code this for me platform but I already trried with wait_for but it won't work too

So I switched to this because I thought maybe this will be functional but same thing again

How do you would code it
or other question do you know a good tutorial for wait_for?

Comment: nevermind 
I tried again with wait_for and now it works the way I wanted thanks for your help

Comment: but now I have two other questions
1st How to let the bot sned wrong when the answer is not the right one?
2nd How to make the bot send the right answer when you answered wrong

Comment: code now is 

```python
if message.content.startswith('-vokabeln'):
        channel = message.channel
        random_vokabel = random.choice(vocab_list)
        await channel.send(random_vokabel)

        if random_vokabel == "suburb":

            def check(m):
                return m.content == 'Vorort' and m.channel == channel

            msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
            await channel.send('richtig!')
```